# Monolingual learner's dictionary with small defining vocabulary

Tags: apprentissage, dictionnaires

Most modern English learner's dictionary use [defining vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defining_vocabulary). It is good idea to define lemmas in a learner's dictionary with just limited number of words and even doing this with [multi-layer strategy](http://learnthesewordsfirst.com/). Which French learner's dictionaries for adults use defining vocabulary?

Comment: +1 for that curious question! It appears that french lexicographers appear to prefer other innovative techniques. Marie-Noëlle Lamy explains that well as part of her "Lexicography: Reference works across time, space and languages". You'll find it partly on google books, start reading from p.174.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that such a dictionary about the French language (as far as I know) exists.

To the best of my understanding of your question the books below could consist of a starting point for constantly increasing French vocabulary for Anglophones.

[Barron's French Vocabulary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764147706)

[Schaum's French](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071828389)

[Building Vocabulary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071836209)

[French vocabulary for English speakers - 9000 words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1780712952)